# merge css into one css file

Tags: css

Over 2 years i have built my website where each JSP page has its own css defined. Now as part of performance optimization i would like to merge these CSS into one css file. How can i merge it without getting affected by same selector names?

For example i have multiple JSP pages define the following selector

```
table.myitemlisttable {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
```

where the name is same but there are differences in the attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing I do to avoid conflicts and keep the number of classes down is give each `body` tag an `id`. Then I can use those as limiting selectors to restrict the scope of my rules. Example, you have a Contact Us page, and a Products page. Products gets:

```
<body id="products">
```

And Contact Us gets

```
<body id="contactus">
```

Each page can have a table with the same class, and in your CSS, you'd just put the `id` in front of the rules.

```
#products table.myitemlisttable {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

#contactus table.myitemlisttable {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
}
```

You could even find things that are consistent on all pages, and pull them out to save lines.

```
table.myitemlisttable {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

#products table.myitemlisttable {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

#contactus table.myitemlisttable {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
}
```

Comment: Absolutely great idea

Comment: Is there a way we can do this for javascript functions?

Comment: With jQuery, you can add selectors like that. `$('.myitemlisttable')` to `$(#products .myitemlisttable)`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Change the class or id by appending a page name to the end. E.g. `table.myitemlisttable_page_items`.
2. Copy + Paste each snippet of CSS into a single CSS page.
3. Rename classes and ids as appropriate and remove any duplicate CSS where possible.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.. I like @misterManSam's answer, but I'd slightly vary it to reduce changing classes in lots of places.

I'd prepend a class or id to my css selector, then wrap (all) my html on each page...

**CSS**

```
.page1 table.myitemlisttable
.page2 table.myitemlisttable
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='page1'> ...existing page1... </div>
```

Comment: Ha, and fools seldom differ. :)